# Curly braces initialization gives "expected a '('..." error messages using g++ 11

Tags: c++, g++

I am using g++ 11.2.0 and also passing the -std=c++11 compiler option, still getting error message when trying to use curly braces in constructor delegation part:

line `: Move{ *source.data } // Gives "expected a '('"`

**What am I missing?**

```
class Move {
private:
    // Declare the raw pointer as
    // the data member of class
    int* data;

public:

    // Constructor
    Move(int d)
    {
        // Declare object in the heap
        data = new int;
        *data = d;
        std::cout << "Constructor is called for "
            << d << std::endl;
    };

    // Copy Constructor
    Move(const Move& source)
        : Move{ *source.data } // Gives "expected a '('"
    {

        // Copying the data by making
        // deep copy
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor is called -"
            << "Deep copy for "
            << *source.data
            << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Should it be Move(source.data) instead?

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/rMx31r8r8).

Comment: Many thx, for all. @RichardCritten . It is capable to compile and run on many online compilers... so it is not an error, I understand what you write is preferable, or workaround, still do not understand why my g++ gives the error...

Comment: @Ian4264 No. The other constructor takes an `int` argument but `source.data` is an `int*`. Also note that the `.` operator has higher precedence than the `*`, so that argument is evaluated (correctly) as `*(source.data)`.

Comment: @Adrian Mole, whoops didn't spot the int pointer 

Comment: Maybe, there are two compilers installed on your box, and your build script somehow picks the one you don't expect. You could try to add the `--version` into the compiler options to become confident.

Comment: Oops. I just noticed that with `--version`, the g++ doesn't compile anything: [test on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04e2f8cc5db9516d)...

Comment: @Scheff'sCat right, with `--version` it prints the version and exits, try `-v` instead.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Perfect! That's much better: [test on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82fb476097f6f043) (Actually, it's a little bit very verbose but contains what's needed.) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are trying to fetch the private variable data of a source and that's illegal. Either declare the variable data public or try to use a function for that purpose.

Comment: No, that's not it. That kind of error would be reported as "_error: int* Move::data' is private within this context_" or something very similar when using g++.